# Use booleans or has_many through?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I've got a Product model, a Statuses model and a Productstatuses model.

```
Product has_many :productstatuses, :dependent => :destroy
Product has_many :statuses, :through => :productstatuses

Status has_many :productstatuses
Status has_many :products, :through => :productstatuses

Productstatus belongs_to :product
Productstatus belongs_to :status
```

I'm using the statuses in two ways.

One, to show progression as a product is making its way through our system (statuses `bookmark, processing, approved`. Once a product has a status of `approved`, it can't move backward in the system (so that I don't create a public 404). A product must have one of these three at all times to be valid.

I also use the statuses for different "flags" on the products:

- `retired` when a product is no longer available (this product will also always have `approved` status; `approved` == publically indexable in our sitemap, but `retired` removes it from everywhere on our site (index, archives, etc) without 404'ing its permalink)
- `pre-sale` when a product is not available yet (could have any of the three above)
- `needs-images` (could have any of the three)

My question is a bit of a two-parter:

1. Should I have just made the "flags" statuses booleans on the Product model? I ask because:
2. How do I write a scope that says `approved but not retired`? Or `approved but not retired and not needs-images`?

With a boolean, I can just have a scope like
`scope :not_foo where(:foo = false)` and chain those all up. I'm drawing a blank on the best way to do the same with the above setup. I thought the `has_many :through` setup was the way to go (the flags as booleans just seemed like a lot of excess `falses` in my database) but database structure/planning is not my strong suit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [state machine](https://github.com/qoobaa/transitions) for the product flow `pre-sale`, `approved` and `retired` and a boolean flag for `needs-images` for indicating additional state which is out of the flow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Any reason why the transitions gem over aasm or the others?

Comment: no big difference, just take a short look on both of them and use the one which will be easier to start, functionalities provided seam to be similar